# Language independant themable CSS in Sharepoint

Tags: css, sharepoint, themes

After a little research it turns out that themable custom css in sharepoint should be placed either in the styles library or in the layouts folder but always in a language dependant folder structure like  `/<LCID>/Styles/Themable`

I would like to replace the target folder of the css files in the package with the primary language of the server where the solution is deployed.

For Example, I want to change

`<TemplateFile Location="Layouts\1031\Styles\mygrid.css" />` to

`<TemplateFile Location="Layouts\1033\Styles\mygrid.css" />` when the solution is deployed.

A solution to this problem would also help for other files which have to be put in the Layouts\LCID directory such as theme xmls themselves.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have only one version of css file (language independent) and you need to put it into the right folder during deployment.

The solution can be to get rid of the language specific folder schema and put your css file into `Layouts\YourProject` folder and then register the css file via [CssRegistration control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.cssregistration.aspx)  on your master page, web part or control.

See also my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128060/sharepoint-register-css-file-out-of-language-specific-folder).