# SharePoint: register css file out of language specific folder

Tags: sharepoint

My css file is in `_layouts/MyProject/css/styles.css` and I need to register it from code behind. For this I should use `CssRegistration.Register` method:

```cs
CssRegistration.Register("MyProject/css/styles.css");
```

But you will get this exception:

> Cannot make a cache safe URL for "1033/styles/MyProject/css/styles.css", file not found. Please verify that the file exists under the layouts directory.

because SharePoint expect the css file in language specific folder e.g. for English `1033/styles`.

*Seems there is no parameter to turn this behavior off!*

On the other hand very similar task, registration of the javascript file, supports such requirement, see the third parameter `localizable`:

```cs
ScriptLink.Register(Page, "MyProject/js/script.js", false);
```

Why the 2 classes for logically the same thing has so different interface? Is there any way how to register css out of the language specific folder? Or the only way is to distribute the same css file to those LCID folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead create a new `CssRegistration` control and add it to the page.  Then include the "/_layouts/" folder in the path

```
CssRegistration cssRegistration = new CssRegistration
{
  After = "corev4.css",
  Name = "/_layouts/MyProject/css/styles.css"
};
Controls.Add(cssRegistration);
```

Comment: Really strange that the property of the class (Name) supports _layout in the path, but the static helper method from the same class (Register) does not support it. Thx, this workaround works.